# CKeditor wont show on dynamically generated modal

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor, bootstrap-modal

i'm using datatable addcolumn to generate dynamic buttons , each of these buttons then will shows a modal in which i want to put a CKeditor instance.

.js

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
```

this code works fine on html page, but when i put it inside modal , it just shows a regular textarea

```
<textarea name="editor"></textarea>
```

what do i miss here ?

Comment: Regardless of how you load/generate a modal, you need to run `CKEDITOR.replace()` *after* the modal is available in the DOM, so e.g. after it's appended to `<body>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
});
```

You have to fire the function after the element is added in the DOM, replace `#myModal` with the selector for your modal and it should work - this should work for the bootstrap modal